# How to debug UI Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Got this runtime warning, how to get line where it happens?

```
runtime: UI API called from background thread: -[UIView bounds] must be used from main thread only
```

Is it any breakpoints i.e. `symbolic breakpoint`for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Main Thread checker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker)** has an option for pausing at the issue. You just need to enable it.

> **EditScheme**->**Run**->**Diagnostics**->**RunTime API Checking**-> Select both **Main
>   Thread Checker** and **Pause On Issues**

[image]

Comment: What to do if I don't have "Runtime API Checking" in diagnostic options?

Comment: @mag_zbc upgrade > Xcode 9. If you have an earlier version the option is not available but neither is the error message.

Comment: @luk2302 you have update your UI using  DispatchQueue.main.async

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Puneet Sharma is good, but it has a downside: it requires Xcode 9. However, what you want is possible in earlier version as well, using symbolic breakpoints

[image: Symbolic breakpoint]

It works, but I noticed it makes the app run dramatically slow, so whenever possible, use Puneet Sharma's method